# jQuery only upload last dragged files

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I followed this [tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/drag-and-drop-file-uploading/) on how to create a DragNDrop file upload.

It basically consists of

```
<form  id='dragform'>
 <input type="file" name="file[]" id="fileC" class="inputfile" multiple />
  <label for="fileC" id='dropLabel'>
  </label>
</form>
```

where the input is hidden.

The upload is done by

```
var $form = $('#dragform');

.on('drop', function(e) 
{
   droppedFiles = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;        
   $form.trigger('submit');
});

var $input = $('.inputfile');

$input.on( 'change', function( e )
{
  $form.trigger('submit');
});

$form.on('submit', function(e)
{
  var ajaxData = new FormData($form.get(0));

  if (droppedFiles) {            
    $.each( droppedFiles, function(i, file) {
    ajaxData.append( $input.attr('name'), file );
    });
  }

 [...]

});
```

This means there are 2 options to upload files, either by selecting or by dropping. In both cases the files are directly uploaded with AJAX. Here comes now my problem:

If I select **file1.pdf** then **ajaxData** only contains **file1.pdf**. If I now drop **file2.pdf** and **file3.pdf** in the DragNDrop area, then **ajaxData** contains **file1.pdf**, **file2.pdf** and **file3.pdf** - but I only want it to contain the dragged files **file2.pdf** and **file3.pdf**, since **file1.pdf** has been uploaded before. If I now select **file4.pdf**, then **ajaxData** includes **file2.pdf**,**file3.pdf** and **file4.pdf**.

What do I need to change, so that I only get the last dragged or last selected files from my form?

Comment: clear `droppedFiles`

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky Thank you! Setting **droppedFiles =""** just before **[...]** works almost. If I first dragged a file and then select a file, the dragged files are no longer included in ajaxData. However, if I first select a file and then drag a file, then the selected file is still included in ajaxData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works now:

```
var ajaxData; 

if (droppedFiles) {
  ajaxData =  new FormData();
  $.each( droppedFiles, function(i, file) {
  ajaxData.append( $input.attr('name'), file );
   });
}
else {
   ajaxData = new FormData($form.get(0));
}
droppedFiles = "";
```